# Как проверить возможность записи в файл в Java?

Tags: java, исключения

Не являюсь программистом, написал небольшую программу, которая парсит один текстовый файл и раскидывает его на много маленьких файлов. В каждый попеременно записывает строчки из основного. Иногда программа выдает ошибку

> файл занят другим процессом

Как обработать это исключение, чтобы в случае недоступности файла "стучаться" пока не станет доступным?

Comment: Использовать цикл while...do. Но вы можете подвесить программу намертво

Comment: Так и обработать, как и все другие исключения - try..catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить, что файл можно прочитать: [`File.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()) либо [`Files.isReadable(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isReadable(java.nio.file.Path)).
Либо можно, как предложили в комментариях, через `try..catch`.

При ошибке ждём секунду, пробуем ещё раз. Только чтобы не было бесконечного цикла, добавим кулдаун.
(А вообще, есть вероятность, что Вы забываете закрывать файл / читаете его, когда выполняется другая операция.)

Вот вариант с рекурсией:

```java
public void read(int countdown)
{
    File f = new File("test.txt");
    /*if (Files.isReadable(f.toPath()))*/
    if (f.canRead())
    {
        // читаем удобным способом
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        ...
        // закрываем поток
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
    else
    {
        if (countdown < 1)
            return;
        read(countdown - 1);
    }
}
```

Вызывать функцию с указанием максимального числа повторов: `read(5);`